# How fileinput.input() works?

Tags: python

When uploading 1.txt containing numbers (5,5,10,10) throws me an error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '5,5,10,10'

The exact content of my file is: 5,5,10,10

What am I doing wrong?

The lower part of the code is used in hackathon to upload data. After for...

Thx!!!

old version:

```
import fileinput

def processLine(inputLine):
.....
return y

for line in fileinput.input("1.txt"):
    inputLine = int(line)
    print(processLine(inputLine))
```

new version:

```
for line in fileinput.input():
    inputLine = line.rstrip("\n")
    inputLine = inputLine.rstrip("")
    inputLine = inputLine.split(' ')
    inputLine = list(map(int,inputLine))
    print(processLine(inputLine))
```

Now it works for my data: 5 5 10 10 
But when I code in hackathon I still get a error: 
DATASET NUMBER: 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./prog.py", line 20, in 
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

How do I know what to correct?

Input
The only line of input consists of 4 space separated integers: x1, y1, x2, y2.
In 50% of test cases:1 <= x1, y1, x2, y2 <= 10^3
In other 50% of test cases: 1 <= x1, y1, x2, y2 <= 10^9.
Output
Number of bee hives inside the described rectangle.

Example
Input
1 1 15 4
Output
0

Input
5 5 10 10
Output
12

Comment: What's the exact content of your file? One number per line? No extraneous characters or whitespace? No blank lines?

Comment: The exact content of your file is: 5,5,10,10

Comment: Your code is trying to convert each line to an integer. The line `5,5,10,10` cannot be converted to an integer. You would need to split it and convert the pieces to integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, `line` is the string `'5,5,10,10'`  (so the issue is not really about `fileinput`, rather just a conversion):

```
line = '5,5,10,10'
int(line)
# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '5,5,10,10'
```

So your are missing a split and map:

```
list_of_input = line.split(',')
list_of_int = map(int, list_of_input)           # python2
list_of_int = list( map(int, list_of_input) )   # python3
# is now [5, 5, 10, 10]
```